# Is binominal the same as boolean?

Tags: definition

In the case of describing an attribute type which has two values (yes or no) is binominal the same as boolean? A source would be great.

Comment: The tag binomial-distribution is quite misleading. Remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't say that. *Binominal* stresses that the item on hand has two names, rather than two values. It is not so appropriate. I'd rather use *bivalued* for a discrete attribute having two cases, such as black/white.

Boolean specifically applies to variables taking values in $\{0,1\}$, which can be mapped to logical values false and true. Boolean algebra (computation with these numbers) parallels the rules of propositional calculus.

Comment: Is there really such a word as "binominal"?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: having or characterized by two names, especially those of genus and species in taxonomies; "binomial nomenclature of bacteria" [no typo]

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP means binomial...

Comment: @MRobinson: I am pretty sure he doesn't know. In any case, not with the mathematical meaning. He also posted on *polynominal*, not referring to polynomials (though he used the tag).

Comment: @YvesDaoust I'm not going to criticise them for a typo/potential language based error. Your answer is still a good one (hence my upvote), obviously Binomial has two values, but not necessary 0,1. I'm just splitting hairs!

Comment: @MRobinson: I don't confirm that. Binomial usually refers to pairs of terms (giving by-products such as the binomial coefficients and distribution), not to split values (pun intended).

Comment: @YvesDaoust You're not wrong, and I think we are coming from the same page. I guess I just think the OP should be given a break!